# Escaping an equal sign in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is broken on line 3 and it's because of the equal sign, but I'm not sure how to escape it. Can someone help me out?

```
  if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category/)) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Chef)) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-chef');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+')) ) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');
  } else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/')) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop');
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this missing a slash at the end?

Comment: There's no problem with the equals sign in this. Like @FabioPoloni said, you haven't closed your regex properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line is missing a slash:

```
  if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category/)) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Chef/)) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-chef');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+')) ) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');
  } else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/')) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop');
  }
```